# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Tuple<string,string,double>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Tuple<string,string,double>>'

Tags: c#, tuples

I have 2 tuples

```
List<Tuple<string, string, double>> _AllBatchList = new List<Tuple<string, string, double>>(); 


List<Tuple<string, string, double>> _tmpBatchList = null;
```

add data in this way

```
for (int row = 0; row < b1MatrixItemD.RowCount; row++)
{ 
    string _WtmpBatchNo = ((EditText)b1MatrixItemD.Columns.Item("Col_0").Cells.Item(row + 1).Specific).Value;   
    string _WtmpItemNo = ((EditText)b1MatrixItemD.Columns.Item("Col_1").Cells.Item(row + 1).Specific).Value;
    double _WtmpTotalQty = 0;   
    double.TryParse(((EditText)b1MatrixItemD.Columns.Item("Col_5").Cells.Item(row + 1).Specific).Value, out _WtmpTotalQty);

    _AllBatchList.Add(new Tuple<string, string, double>(_WtmpBatchNo, _WtmpItemNo, _WtmpTotalQty));
}
```

which I want to filter data and assign same type of tuple type

```
_tmpBatchList = _AllBatchList.Find(t => t.Item2 == _WtmpItemNo);
```

and iterate through the tuple

```
foreach (var item in _tmpBatchList)
{   
    doc.Lines.BatchNumbers.BatchNumber = item.Item1;    
    doc.Lines.BatchNumbers.Quantity = double.Parse(_WtmpTotalQty);
    doc.Lines.BatchNumbers.Add();
}
```

but this line generate above error

```
_tmpBatchList = _AllBatchList.Find(t => t.Item2 == _WtmpItemNo)
```

**Need advice to resolve this issue**

Comment: what is `AllBatchList`? Or, did you mean `_AllBatchList`?

Comment: Did you post all the code?

Comment: @Xiaoy312 please refer the modified code

Comment: You changed which line is throwing the error... Are you sure it is the new line with is causing the exception?

Comment: @wannadream code is complete

Comment: @HereticMonkey _tmpBatchList = _AllBatchList.Find(t => t.Item2 == _WtmpItemNo) generates error

Comment: [`Find()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.find?view=netframework-4.7.2) returns a single element in a list. I think you want [`Where()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Comment: Check doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.7.2#methods

Comment: Read my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Find()` method will return an object of type `Tuple<string, string, double>` in this case.

You are trying to assign it to a variable of type `List<Tuple<string, string, double>>`, hence the error.

Try assigning the object found to a variable instead:

```
var obj = _AllBatchList.Find(t => t.Item2 == _WtmpItemNo);
```

If what you are trying to do is find all items that satisfy this condition, use the `Where` method instead:

```
_tmpBatchList = _AllBatchList.Where(t => t.Item2 == _WtmpItemNo);
```

Comment: where is the correct way for my question , so far ok